# Does heating an air permeable container affect the dew point inside it?

Tags: humidity

I know that the dew point is only affected by pressure and amount of water in the air so temperature should not affect it. However, I was wondering about a situation where there was a container with porous walls that was heated from inside. Since the container would be air permeable, the pressure inside it should be the atmospheric pressure. Therefore, according to the ideal gas law pV=nRT, the rise in temperature would need to be compensated by lowering of n since the left side of the equation would remain unchanged. Wouldn't this in turn mean less water thus lower dew point?

However, in a psychrometric chart the amount of water is given as g of water per g of dry air. This would indicate that the dew point wouldn't change because the lowering of n would also affect air?

So the question is does heating an air permeable container affect the dew point inside it, and if it does, how to take this effect into account when calculating the dew point?

Comment: The dew point is affected by temperature as hotter air can hold more water.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Since the container would be air permeable". Do you mean a container whose walls are porous? And if it allows air to enter or exit, then how can you use the ideal equation since  inside the container would not be constant. I think you need to more clearly describe what you are doing. Right now it is very unclear, at least to me.

Comment: @BobD I think the OP means a container with porous walls as he writes that $n$ changes.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria OK. But then do he walls permit heat transfer from within the container to the atmosphere outside the atmosphere? If it does, how do you keep the temperature constant?. I supposed you could have a constant heat source  in the container. But if heat transfer is simultaneously occurring to the atmosphere, there will be temperature gradients in the in the air of the chamber, meaning you won't have a single equilibrium temperature in the container. Without equilibrium, you can't use the ideal gas law. This whole thing is very confusing.

Comment: @BobD I think the OP assumes that there is no heat transfer through the walls (except for convection). But there the OP should clarify.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria You're making my point. To many things to clarify.

Comment: If you can respond to my comments and clarify what you are  describing, I will attempt an answer. As it stands, however, I think your post will be closed for being unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried to edit the question to be more clear. I mean a container with porous walls or at least holes in the walls. Even though there would be temperature gradients in this case, couldn't you still assume that the gradients would be outside the container and the inside of the container would be heated uniformly?